# Asking a GUI application to select all the text

Tags: x11

Can an external program ask a GUI application (for example: Gedit, Firefox) to select all the text of the active widget?

--

EDIT: I am looking for the equivalent of pressing `Control+A`, because blindly sending key presses has proven to be not reliable, as in my former question: [`xdotool` does not send keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214909/xdotool-does-not-send-keys)

EDIT2: I am assuming that the GUI app already has focus.

Comment: Yes, but the program must ask the desktop environments clipboard, not t he program itself.

Comment: What program can do that?

Comment: [Unix Clipboards](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44204/access-unix-clipboard)

Comment: I knew that there was `xsel`, but `xsel` only lets you access something that has already been selected. I am looking for the equivalent of `Control+A` in many programs, but without sending key presses.

Comment: As far as I know that isn't possible as to select text, the app you're selecting from must have Active Focus.  There are many ways t set/get focus but you still need to know which text you selected.  You do that by examining the contents of the clipboard etc.

Comment: I forgot to say that the app has focus.  So, once a GUI app has focus, how can you tell it to select all the text in the current widget?

Comment: You must use Control + A, then scan the clipboard

Comment: I explicitly said that I don't want to use `Control+A` (and I actually can't: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214909/xdotool-does-not-send-keys)

Comment: Then you need to find a different way, as Control+A is the only way to select Text